# how to use different pubspec.yaml in different environmnet with flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, pubspec

is it possible to use different pubspec.yaml in different environmnet? for example, in develop environment I use the dependencies from local folder, and config the local folder in the pubspec.yaml like this:

```
dependencies:
  info:
    path: ../common/info
```

in production environment I use the dependencies like this:

```
dependencies:
  info: 1.0.0
```

is it possible to do like that? I do not want to change the pubspec.yaml every time. I have read the solution from here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45769 but I am not sure it is the proper way.

Comment: How about using git for it?

Comment: put the pubspec.yaml in different branch of git?@YeasinSheikh

Comment: yea . something like this

Comment: I think it is better than override and allow failure.